# Using docker for Celery Task +Rabbitmq not working on python 3.7

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

I am using Docker to setup periodic task with Celery+RabbitMQ in DJANGO Project.
Using new versions of packages:
Python: 3.7
Celery: 4.4.0rc1
Django: 2.2.5

Getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 241, in find_app
worker_1  |     found = sym.app
worker_1  | AttributeError: module 'modulename' has no attribute 'app'
worker_1  | 
worker_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
worker_1  | 
worker_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 10, in <module>
worker_1  |     sys.exit(main())
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
worker_1  |     main()
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
worker_1  |     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
worker_1  |     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
worker_1  |     argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
worker_1  |     self.app = self.find_app(app)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
worker_1  |     return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 246, in find_app
worker_1  |     found = sym.celery
worker_1  | AttributeError: module 'modulename' has no attribute 'celery'
```

I am stuck how to use Celery, celery-beat, RabbitMQ, Docker along with Django Project for my asynchronous task which i want to run periodically for my django project. I am novice in Django, please help me out.

I have tried with Django-celery but django-celery is only compatible till celery<=4.0, so to use new version of celery I have removed the django-celery from django project. But now then i face the above error.

If you use celery==3.3.0, django=1.8.4, python=2.7 and django-celery=3.3.1 , then celery uses default broker i.e. amqp://guest:guest@localhost//  But to work on docker, we need to change localhost to rabbitmq Ip. So this step also fails

Requirements.txt

```
#amqp==1.4.9
#amqp==2.3.2
anyjson==0.3.3
astroid==1.4.6
#billiard==3.3.0.23
#billiard==3.6.1.0
boto==2.38.0
#celery==3.1.26.post2
#celery>=4.2.0rc4
#celery==4.1.0
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.7
#Django==1.8.4
django-braces==1.8.1
#django-celery==3.3.1
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-extensions==1.5.7
django-fcm==0.1.1
django-filter==0.11.0
#django-guardian>=1.4.6
django-oauth-toolkit==0.9.0
django-push-notifications==1.4.1
django-rest-swagger==0.3.5
django-storages==1.1.8
djangorestframework==3.2.4
drfdocs==0.0.6
ecdsa==0.13.2
enum34==1.1.6
future==0.17.1
geopy==1.11.0
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.6
jsonfield==1.0.3
jwt==0.3.2
Klout==0.1.3
#kombu==3.0.37
#kombu==4.2.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
Markdown==2.6.2
meld3==1.0.2
mongoengine==0.10.0
nltk==3.0.5
#numpy==1.17.1
numpy==1.16.5
oauthlib==1.0.1
opentok==2.10.0
pdfkit==0.5.0
Pillow==2.9.0
psycopg2==2.8.3
pyasn1==0.4.5
pycrypto==2.6.1
pydot==1.4.1
PyJWT==1.4.0
pylint==1.5.6
pymongo==3.1
pyparsing==2.4.2
PyPDF2==1.26.0
python-jose==3.0.1
python-memcached==1.59
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.12
pytz==2015.7
PyYAML==5.1.2
reportlab==3.3.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
rsa==4.0
scikit-learn==0.20.3
#scipy==1.3.1
scipy==1.2.2
shortuuid==0.4.2
six==1.9.0
sklearn==0.0
urllib3==1.22
validate-email==1.3
wrapt==1.10.8
xhtml2pdf==0.0.6
xmltodict==0.10.1
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('projectname')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
# app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',

)
```

I want celery beat to run after every one minute executing the different tasks in my django project

Comment: How are you running the celery? Where are you initializing the `celery` app?

Comment: in dockerfile by calling
ENTRYPOINT celery -A audetemi worker --loglevel=info

Comment: Where are you importing the `celery.py` file?

Comment: I am importing at task definition

Comment: The issue is how you are starting celery with the command line.  What is the location of the celerypy file?